# No registered devices for parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "appid" ,"client Id");

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                Logger.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");

            } else {
                Logger.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push"+ e);
            }
        }
    });
```

It goes inside "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel" but when I try to push it says

> You have no registered installations of your app. You can get started with our Quick Start guide.

I have tried switching into data network as well but still does not work.
Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should register your app at background control of parse.

Comment: Is it really necessary to register the app even for testing?

Comment: Parse.initialize(this, "appid" ,"client Id"); where did you get appid?

Comment: Inside the app name by going to Settings --> Keys

Comment: exactly, id's provided in the setting>keys.And check the package name is correct in manifest file in permission tag and in receiver tag .

Comment: yes i have the correct package name in it.

Comment: Just go to Quick Start guide as it said!

Comment: i already did go through it.. and this was my problem

Answer (score 0):

No need for **subscribeInBackground**.
Make sure you have set *Application* class inside Manifest.xml

```
<application
         android:name=".ParseSample"
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And define your keys inside your **Application** class.

```
public class ParseSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "KEY");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    } }
```